# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |S_n-\sigma_n|^2$ converges implies $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges also

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $\left\{a_n\right\}$ be real,
> \begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
> S_n=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n,\qquad \sigma_n=\frac{1}{n+1}(S_1+S_2+\cdots+S_n).
> \end{aligned}\end{equation*}
> Suppose that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty |S_n-\sigma_n|^2$ converges. Show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges also.

It sounds that no idea. Write $S_n-\sigma_n=\frac{S_n+\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k)S_k}{n+1}$, what to do next? Just square it gives more awful things. Any ideas to write it in other form?

Comment: This is related to Cesàro_summation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation In particular, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sigma_n$ is almost the Cesàro_summation of $\{a_n\}.$

Comment: @AdamRubinson Actually it can be treated as the Cesàro summation by defining $a_0=0.$ Then $S_0=0$ and we gain one (artificial)  term in the definition of $\sigma_n.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\sigma_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\left (1-{k\over n+1}\right )a_k$$
Therefore
$$v_n:=S_n-\sigma_n={1\over n+1}\sum_{k=1}^nka_k,\quad na_n=(n+1)v_n-nv_{n-1}$$
Therefore $$a_n={(n+1)v_n-nv_{n-1}\over n}=v_n-v_{n-1}+{v_n\over n}$$
Since $v_n$ is square summable, then $v_n\to 0.$ Hence the telescoping series $\sum (v_n-v_{n-1})$ is convergent. Furthermore
$$2{|v_n|\over n}\le |v_n|^2 +{1\over n^2}$$
Hence the series $\sum a_n$ is convergent.